# How to unit test material2 icons

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular-material2

This componenet uses material icons.

[image]

Now I'm trying to learn unit testing using karma (via angular cli/webpack) and I have the majority of the configuration figured out to create the component, but I'm struggling to understand how to configure for material icons.

Here is what I have created so far:

[image]

```
/* config */
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { TickerDirective } from '../../directives/ticker.directive';
import { MdIconModule, MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MdIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon';

/* my stuff */
import { FoodListComponent } from './food-list.component';
import { FoodDataService } from '../../services/food-items/food-data.service';
import { FoodItem } from '../../diet/food-item';
import { WorkingData } from '../../services/working-data/working-data';
import { WorkingDataService } from '../../services/working-data/working-data.service';

describe('FoodListComponent', () => {
  let component:          FoodListComponent;
  let fixture:            ComponentFixture<FoodListComponent>;
  let foodDataService:    FoodItem[];
  let workingDataService: WorkingData;
  let de:                 DebugElement[];
  let el:                 HTMLElement;

  /* Stub Services */
  let foodDataServiceStub = [{
    name: 'test food name ..................', // written long to trigger the ticker directive
    img: './no_image.png',
    description: 'test food description'
  }];

  let workingDataServiceStub = {
    today: new Date(),
    selectedDate: new Date(2016, 2, 5),
    targetDate: new Date(2016, 2, 7),
    data: {exercise: 'Squat'}
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ FoodListComponent, TickerDirective ],
      imports: [ MaterialModule.forRoot(), MdIconModule], // not sure if this is correct
      providers: [
        { provide: FoodDataService, useValue: foodDataServiceStub },
        { provide: WorkingDataService, useValue: workingDataServiceStub } ,
        MdIconRegistry // not sure if this is correct
      ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FoodListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    /* Inject services */
    foodDataService = TestBed.get(FoodDataService);
    workingDataService = TestBed.get(WorkingDataService);

    /* Assign Services */
    component.workingData = workingDataService;
    component.foods = foodDataService;

    fixture.detectChanges();
    de = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('span'));
    el = de[0].nativeElement;
    // console.log(el);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
  it('should have the correct food name', () => {
    expect(el.textContent).toContain('test food name ..................');
  });
});
```

**Material Icons**
You can see the ligatures of the material icons, but they are not rendering. I read that I needed to import `Http` but that through an error.

Answer (score 7):

I've stumbled upon the same problem in unit testing my components and after finding nothing on the internet I decided to implement this myself.

For Angular-CLI users:
Add the following snippet at the end of your `test.ts` file.

```
const materialIcons = document.createElement('link');
materialIcons.href = 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
materialIcons.rel = 'stylesheet';
document.head.appendChild(materialIcons);
```

Comment: I'll give this a try sometime. Thanks.

Comment: This is the only way I've found that works, is this still the case?!

Comment: 2023 and I have found no other way than this that works!